# Block container box in css

Tags: html, css

Consider the following `HTML` markup:

```
<div>
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

In the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes) siad that every block-level element is also a block container box. Thus for the `Some text` inside the `<p>` an anonymous block-level box and hence will be displayed as, for instance, it will be inside the `div` element with no format additionally:

```
<div>
    <p> <div> Some text </div> </p>
</div>
```

Is my above reasoning true? I want to understand more precisely when the anonymous block-level box is generated.

Comment: @Sajad Lfc I need in answer to my question.

Comment: im not really sure what the question is but putting a `div` inside of a `p` is not valid html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P elements are only allowed to contain inline elements.

```
<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->
```

This is consistent with http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1, which says that the P element "cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)."

Comment: Does it mean that `Some text` contained inside the anonymous inline-level box?

Comment: In HTML Mark up <div>
    <p>Some text</p>
</div> Some text is contained inside a block level/inline element, which itself is in other block element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,every block-level element is also a block container box,i think your problem is,
**how to know it?**

just give **borders**,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/757TN/)

```
<div id="test">
    <p> <div id="test1"> Some text </div> </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#test{

    border:1px solid #000;
}
#test1{

 border:1px solid #000;    
}
p
{
    border:1px solid #000;    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: How do you know if an element is block or inline?

A: You have to memorize inline (p, span, b, em, I, site, mark, code) and block (p, div, form, header, nav, ul li, h1) elements.

Q: Elements can "transmogrify" between block and inline. How can you tell which is which?

A: Look at the format, or look at the css. An inline element with a tall height has been changed to a block element.

In this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/t9K5K/), you'll five both block and inline elements that have been displayed as both block and inline by changing the css.

CSS

```
p, span, div {
    margin-top:10px;
}
.displayblock {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin: 10px auto;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
.displayinline {
    display: inline;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin: 10px auto;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
```